# CSS selection and effects

Tags: css, selector, effect

Heelo guys ! 
I need a hand with CSS.

I would like to do an effect on all the item when one of them is clicked.

```
#scrollBox #content .item:active (?)
{
    width: 0px;
}
#scrollBox #content .item
{   
    width : 100%;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-out;    
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease-out;
    transition: all 1s ease-out;
}
```

I don't know is there is something which could replace (?) to get what I want ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Try `#scrollBox #content:active .item` as your first selector: http://jsfiddle.net/vamf2/1/

Comment: That's not what i want, unfortunately

Comment: `effect on all the item when one of them is clicked.` ... sounds like you need JavaScript

Comment: There's really no other way to do it with just CSS. Can you explain a bit better what you're trying to do?

Comment: That what I thought, I didn't want to face reality